# The unity images are compressed in one space, what can I do?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

[for some kind of reason, and as you can see in the picture attached, all of the work which is 4 pictures(letting the user choose between 4 picture) is compressed into one space on top of each other, so behind the 2 pics you see are another 2 pics and it does that after saving the project and reopening it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qFtp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact reason, but you can try adding a "grid layout group" to pictures' parent gameobject, it will control their alignment and should store all the pictures in a grid